What's the difference between 'to go on a walk' and 'to go for a walk' if any?
Is it grammatically correct to say to go on a walk? Does it mean something different to 'to go for a walk"?

The former suggests an organised event, for example a 20 km charity walk. The latter seems more casual.

This question is similar to: Go for/on a trip. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

(It's a different question, I don't necessarily think this needs to be closed, but there's good discussion there and the topic of 'on a walk' vs 'for a walk' comes up.)

@Kaia in the similar question "go for a trip" isn't idiomatic, whereas this question has valid meanings for both, although as you say it is addressed in this answer.

@WeatherVane I disagree with the first comment; to me they're both equally appropriate for a casual stroll, and unlikely for an organized event (where I might use something involving "in," like "I was in a walk," or more likely "participated in a [charity/fundraising/etc.] walk."

@AndyBonner I've never heard of someone being in a walk. In a race, yes.

You should ask dogs if they want to go  for a walk.  It would be a decent cartoon in an ESL magazine to have a non-native-speaker asking a dog "Wanna go on a walk?"

@AndyBonner but you changed the use case. You wouldn't say "I was for a walk" either.

''Go for a walk'' sounds unplanned (I am going for a walk to get some fresh air), ''go on a walk'' sounds more like it was planned.

Very little difference.
"Go for" suggests a fairly short pleasure walk, the purpose is "to walk".

In summer, after dinner, I like to go for a walk with my wife.

"Go on" suggest a more serious walk, longer, perhaps organised by someone else, with purpose of "seeing sights" or "reaching a particular place" (not just walking)

I'm going on a 50km walk along the South downs this weekend from Arundel to Brighton.

But the difference seems very minor and there would be a lot of overlap, so don't worry too much.

There’s also the distinction that for suggests the purpose of leaving, whereas on suggests the activity undertaken. ‘Go for a walk’ can mean ‘leave where I am now in order to take a walk’, which ‘go on a walk’ cannot. So in theory, at least (probably not often in practice) you might say, “He went [out] for a walk, but he barely made it out the door before the rain drove him back in”; using on there would sound odd, since it implies the walk actually took place. But again, that’s very minor and unlikely to ever cause any real issues.

Interestingly, Google ngrams shows the more casual "go for a walk" is much more common  than the more serious "go on a walk". On the other hand, "go on a hike" is almost as common as "go for a hike", aligning with the connotation of purpose, organization, or strenuousness.

@NuclearHoagie: That fits in perfectly with this answer.  Going on a hike is a larger and more likely to be formal or at least preplanned occasion and so it is the “on a hike” version, but the spontaneous version does still happen and people generally feel that should be described as going for a hike…
